# Is it possible for "view page source" to return different data to Google Scripts' "UrlFetchApp"?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to find a specific source of data programmatically on a page:

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/3DP.AX/financials?p=3DP.AX

When I "view page source" on the page, I only find once instance of:

```
,"3DP.AX":
```

after which the data I require occurs. So in my code, I have:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/3DP.AX/financials?p=3DP.AX").getContentText().indexOf(",\"3DP.AX\":")
```

^^ this however returns -1

I managed to find the data I need in the response of UrlFetchApp and discovered it occurs after:

```
{"quoteData":{"3DP.AX":
```

However, I cannot find this string in view page source. I cleared my cache and this didn't change the page source results.

**Question:** Is it possible for the data on "view page source" to be different from the data returned by UrlFetchApp?

Comment: Are you asking a question about something which you experimentally determined to be true? There is a lot of difference in behavior between a browser session and `UrlFetchApp`.

Comment: @tehhowch, kind of, I have experimentally determined this to be a possible explanation why my indexOf function doesn't work on the string that is returned by UrlFetchApp but works on the string accessible via view page source. My question now is how to get access the view page source string? Or is it better practice to work with what UrlFetchApp returns?

Comment: Why do you need the same string as that obtained by "view page source"? You mention the data shows up in JSON sent to you... Just use that.

Comment: @tehhowch, because I use "view page source" to search for the data I need and identify the json within which it exists. To do this using UrlFetchApp requires more effort which I am trying to avoid if possible.

Comment: Just log the JSON from the fetch response to something useful - like Stackdriver - and then you can determine the property access path needed, e.g. `var my data = resp["quoteData"]["some key"]...`

Answer (score 1):

It  is possible for there to be a difference between what UrlFetchApp.fetch receives and what a browser request receives. However, you don't have enough information to reach that conclusion based on your current code.

To access the results of a Fetch request, you need to call `getContentText()` on the result, currently you are calling indexOf on an HTTPResponse object, not the text body of the response.

Additionally, you should pass a proper string literal to `indexOf()` - `indexOf(',"3DP.AX":')`

Comment: Thank you for the response. My code snippet was an attempt to shorten it down, but I left out 2 details, which actually address the main issues you raised (although in my code, I used String(<my_code), I have not replaced it with getContextText(). The result remains the same and suggest the string returned is different form the string when I view page source. Is there a way to get the same string as that which is view-able with view page source?